# Slick carousel, two rows of 3 but only scroll the last 2 elements, not all 6 at a time

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Ok, so I've set up Slick Carousel as a block of 6, I would like to scroll the last 2 only at a time, but I can't figure out how to do it.

My code looks like:

```
$('.product-slider').slick({
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 4000,
    slidesToScroll: 1, <-- I would have thought this would have worked, as it does if it's not in a row?
    slidesToShow: 1,
    dots: false,
    slidesPerRow: 3,
    rows: 2,
    responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 478,
      settings: {
        slidesPerRow: 1,
        rows: 1,
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: please create a [mcve]

Comment: but I'm pretty sure it's just an option as per the slick carousel options. Just don't know which one... Seems like a waste of time when I'm 100% sure it's simple and someone will know it.

Comment: Never heard of a slider that shows multiple elements and doesn't scroll all of the shown elements - eg when you scroll the last 2 what happens to the first?

Comment: so for example, you have 12 images, 2 sets of 6, you want to show 2, 4, 6 and then show 4, 6, 8, then 6, 8, 10, etc.

Comment: https://codepen.io/origarti/pen/jVzRqe <-- this, but scrolling just one instead of both at once

Comment: Yeah, not sure that is possible out of the box - if you see the code, it will probably wrap both rows in a div which will be scrolled, think you would probably need to write your own bespoke thing

Comment: Oh, ok--cheers Pete